# Dismissing a Modal View Controller using the UI Alert View Button

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uialertview

I am new to **Xcode** somewhat. Right now I am creating a `view controller` (displaying modally) which displays a form for users to input information, and click "submit" to submit the information.

I created my `IBAction`, and implemented a `UIAlerView` that informs the user the information has been sent. I would like the "Ok" button within my alert view to take them back to the original view controller. I set my `Alert View delegate` and implemented the following method in my .m file:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

When I test it, nothing happens. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement `- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex` delegate method ---

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    //dissmiss here
    //Pre iOS 6.0
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    //From iOS 5.0
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

You can also check for the button which tapped,

```
if(buttonIndex != [alertView cancelButtonIndex]) {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Do I have to implement both methods, or just the method you posted?

Comment: dismissModalViewController was depreciated some time ago, you should edit your answer to use the new method.

Comment: I've also edited the answer as per the @rdelmar comment! If it helps you, mark it as the accepted answer so it will be useful for others!

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the below mentioned delegate method of UIAlertView:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *buttonTitle = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if ([buttonTitle isEqual:@"Ok"]) // Check for Ok button
    {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**SWIFT 5**

I have been away form Xcode since swift 3 and needed to do this in my new project. The below code worked for me (it presents an alert and upon closing the alert, the user is taken back to the previous view controller):

```
func displayAlert() {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Your Title",
                                  message: "Your Message",
                                  preferredStyle: .alert)
    let defaultButton = UIAlertAction(title: "OK",
                                      style: .default) {(_) in
                                        // your defaultButton action goes here
                                        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    alert.addAction(defaultButton)
    present(alert, animated: true) {
        // completion goes here
    }
}
```